# NodeJS Request library not returning elapsed time for event 'response'

Tags: node.js

I am using the NodeJS request library to make some GET requests to a bunch of urls using the code below :

CASE A :

```
  request.get({url : urls[url],time: true}).on('response',function(response){

            console.log(JSON.stringify(response))
            console.log(response.elapsedTime)

        })
        .on('error', function(err) {

            console.error(err)

        })
```

CASE B :

```
request.get({url : urls[url],time: true},function(error, response, body){

                if(!error)
                console.log(response.elapsedTime)

           })
```

I expect the elapsed time to be present in the JS object `response` in both cases. 
However, it is NOT present in CASE A when I am using events and is very much present in CASE B when using normal callback.

Is it a bug or I am missing something? How to get elapsedTime when using events with the request library?

Answer (score 0):

According to docs `elapsedTime` is property only attached to the callback of requests main method, so it works only in the form of `request(options, callback)`, response event returns only the instance of `http.IncomingMessage`.

Although, there is a `request` property on `response` but I'm not sure if that is just a default prototype value. Give it a try: `response.request.elapsedTime`

Comment: Thank you for responding.I had printed the stringified object and it didn't contain it.